# SQL: Why LIKE doesn't work if character class [0-9] is used?

Tags: mysql, sql, case, sql-like

Let's say I have a table:

**Current table:**

```
title_id        title_name               title_qty
   1       A.I. Artificial Intelligence      2
   2       Batman Begins                    40
   3       2012                              7
   4       101 Dalmatians                   23
   5       Act of Valor                      1
   6       Batman                           50
   7       20 Million Miles to Earth       340
```

I would like to have an output of:

**Desired output:**

```
   title_id        title_name               title_qty  title_char
       4          101 Dalmatians                23          #
       7          20 Million Miles to Earth     340         #
       3                2012                    7           #
       1          A.I. Artificial Intelligence  2           A
       5          Act of Valor                  1           A
       6          Batman                        50          B
       2          Batman Begins                 40          B
```

Based on what I read here in Stack Overflow, the fastest way to check if a character is a number is to use LIKE '[0-9]%' so I came up with

**Query:**

> SELECT *, CASE WHEN LEFT(title_name,1) LIKE '[0-9]%' THEN "#" ELSE
>   LEFT(title_name,1) END as title_char FROM title ORDER BY title_name

**Output:**

```
title_id        title_name               title_qty  title_char
   4          101 Dalmatians                23          1
   7          20 Million Miles to Earth     340         2
   3                2012                    7           2
   1          A.I. Artificial Intelligence  2           A
   5          Act of Valor                  1           A
   6          Batman                        50          B
   2          Batman Begins                 40          B
```

As shown above, it doesn't work at all. But if I change the LIKE to match a single digit, it works:

> SELECT *, CASE WHEN LEFT(title_name,1) **LIKE '1%'** THEN "#" ELSE
>   LEFT(title_name,1) END as title_char FROM title ORDER BY title_name

```
title_id        title_name               title_qty  title_char
   4          101 Dalmatians                23          #
   7          20 Million Miles to Earth     340         2
   3                2012                    7           2
   1          A.I. Artificial Intelligence  2           A
   5          Act of Valor                  1           A
   6          Batman                        50          B
   2          Batman Begins                 40          B
```

I initially thought that it doesn't work because my query is a bit complicated so I did a simple SELECT WHERE. The LIKE is added after the WHERE.

**No output (when there should be three):**

```
SELECT * FROM title WHERE title_name LIKE '[0-9]%' ORDER BY title_name
```

**Working as expected:**

```
SELECT * FROM title WHERE title_name LIKE '1%' ORDER BY title_name 

SELECT * FROM title WHERE title_name LIKE '2%' ORDER BY title_name
```

According to the SQL documentation,

> A character class “[...]” matches any character within the brackets.
>   For example, “[abc]” matches “a”, “b”, or “c”. To name a range of
>   characters, use a dash. “[a-z]” matches any letter, whereas **“[0-9]”
>   matches any digit.**

Anyone knows why it doesn't work if you used character class [0-9]? As a beginner, please do correct me if I am wrong. But I am curious why it works if I use LIKE '1%' or any digit while LIKE '[0-9]%' won't give any result? Documentation says it should match any digit right? If casting it as integer is a requirement it shouldn't work on all my tests, right? Because I didn't cast it before doing the LIKE comparison.

**SQL fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/492906/7

Comment: I edited the question... Just to add this is the query that can produce the right output, I used RLIKE:  SELECT *, CASE WHEN LEFT(title_name,1) RLIKE '[0-9]' THEN "#" ELSE LEFT(title_name,1) END as title_char FROM title ORDER BY title_name

Comment: [The documentation you quote](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/pattern-matching.html) is about `RLIKE`, not `LIKE`, so that seems correct to me. In other SQL dialects, `[...]` is accepted by `LIKE`, but (apparently) not in MySQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/pattern-matching.html) is a bit confusing. I hope careful snipping can make it clearer:

> MySQL provides standard SQL pattern matching as well as a form of pattern matching
>
> [...]
>
> SQL pattern matching enables you to use “`_`” to match any single character and “`%`” to match an arbitrary number of characters (including zero characters). In MySQL, SQL patterns are case-insensitive by default. Some examples are shown here. You do not use `=` or `<>` when you use SQL patterns; use the `LIKE` or `NOT LIKE` comparison operators instead.
>
> [...]
>
> The other type of pattern matching provided by MySQL uses extended regular expressions. When you test for a match for this type of pattern, use the `REGEXP` and `NOT REGEXP` operators (or `RLIKE` and `NOT RLIKE`, which are synonyms).
>
> [...]
>
> A character class “`[...]`” matches any character within the brackets. For example, “`[abc]`” matches “`a`”, “`b`”, or “`c`”. To name a range of characters, use a dash. “`[a-z]`” matches any letter, whereas “`[0-9]`” matches any digit.

Since that last sentence is under "the other type of pattern matching", it only applies to the `RLIKE` that you've already found, not to `LIKE`.

Comment: Hi thanks hvd! I got confused. Probably because I found a post here in Stack Overflow recommending LIKE[0-9] for checking if a character is a digit so I thought it will work. Thanks, everything is clear now! Sorry SO if my question is so simple and silly, let me know if it should be deleted. Anyhow, thanks again I am learning a lot from here!

Comment: Everything's simple and silly once you know why. :) Don't worry about it, it's a perfectly good question.